# Converting synchrous to asynchrous method in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have gone through several post for converting existing synchronous method to asynchronous. So based on what I have read I am converting the synchronous method to asynchronous like below

**Synchronous**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int DoWork()
    {
        return DoLongRunningWork();
    }

    public int DoLongRunningWork()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I converted this to Asynchronous version like below

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task<int> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return await DoLongRunningWorkAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> DoLongRunningWorkAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return Task.Run(() => 1);
    }
}
```

I am calling this from Main() Method

```
    static void Main()
    {           
        Someclass worker = new SomeClass();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var result = worker.DoWorkAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

1. Is this a correct way to convert synchronous to asynchronous method?
2. I was expecting Main method's `ManagedThreadId` will be different than `DoWorkAsync` and `DoLongRunningWorkAsync` method's `ManagedThreadId`. But they are same, why?

---

I used `Thread.Sleep()` just to simulate the long running method. As per the suggestions below i should have used `Task.Delay()` to avoid any confusion.
I dont think i have to put my actual business logic here to understand the concept of async.

As per Stephen Cleary
1> Identify the naturally-asynchronous operations your code is doing.
2>Change the lowest-level API calls to invoke asynchronous APIs (with await) instead of synchronous APIs.

***However none of the .Net Libarary methods im using inside `LongRunningMethod` are naturally-asynchronous or awaitable and also `LongRunningMethod` is not doing any I/O operation.***

Requirement

I have Web API which takes JSON string as input. The JSON needs to be transformed into some C# object. For transformation I am building a C# library which takes JSON string as input and then Transform that JSON string into C# objects based on some rules. The library may take time ( few milliseconds) for Transformation,  during this I DO NOT want Web API's main thread to block. The main thread should be free to take any other request while the transformation is going on background thread (some other thread).

```
public class MyWebApi: ApiController
{

    private ILib _myLibrary

    public MyWebApi(ILib myLibrary)
    {
       _myLibrary = myLibrary
    }

    publi async Task<SomeObject> Transform(string jsonString)
    {
          // i want to make LongRunningMethod() method awaitable
          // or at least it needs to execute on different thread  so that 
          // main thread will be free.

         var result = await _myLibrary.LongRunningMethod(jsonString);
         return result;
    }
}

publi class MyLibrary:ILib
{


   // A method that does Transformation
   public async Task<SomeObject> LongRunningMethod(string jsonString)
   {
       var result = new SomeObject();

       // parse jsonString here
       // and based on some complex rules create SomeObject
       // this operation may takes time (lets say few milliseconds)
       // i may call some other private methods here or public methods from other library          
       return result
   }    
}
```

Comment: `DoLongRunningWorkAsync` is completely synchronous... So there is really no "conversion from sync to async" in your post.

Comment: Without a real code example, it's impossible to offer specific advice. For sure, the above code is pointless. The `DoWorkAsync()` method has no apparent need to `await`, so making it `async` isn't useful. The `DoLongRunningWorkAsync()` inserts a _synchronous_ delay into the call. Why you sleep at all I have no idea, but doing so at that point doesn't make any sense. But given the lack of a real example, I can't tell if you just messed up your question, or if your real-world code is similarly broken.

Answer (score 2):

> based on what I have read I am converting the synchronous method to asynchronous like below

The best way to convert synchronous methods to asynchronous (as I describe in my [async brownfield article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx)) is the following:

1. Identify the naturally-asynchronous operations your code is doing. This is anything that is not running CPU code, e.g., I/O.
2. Change the lowest-level API calls to invoke asynchronous APIs (with `await`) instead of synchronous APIs.
3. Note the compiler warning and change your calling method to be `async` with a proper (`Task`/`Task<T>`) return type. Also add an `Async` suffix.
4. Change calling methods to use `await`, and repeat step (3).

When you run into problems with step (3), check out my articles on [async OOP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html), [async MVVM](http://stephencleary.com/publications/) (if applicable), and [async brownfield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

Applying these to your code:

> 1. Identify the naturally-asynchronous operations your code is doing. This is anything that is not running CPU code, e.g., I/O.

Your lowest-level method has a call to `Thread.Sleep`, which is not running code. The asynchronous equivalent is `Task.Delay`.

> 2. Change the lowest-level API calls to invoke asynchronous APIs (with `await`) instead of synchronous APIs.

```
public int DoLongRunningWork()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  return 1;
}
```

> 3. Note the compiler warning and change your calling method to be `async` with a proper (`Task`/`Task<T>`) return type. Also add an `Async` suffix.

```
public async Task<int> DoLongRunningWorkAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  return 1;
}
```

> 4. Change calling methods to use `await`, and repeat step (3).

```
public int DoWork()
{
  return await DoLongRunningWorkAsync();
}
```

> 3. Note the compiler warning and change your calling method to be `async` with a proper (`Task`/`Task<T>`) return type. Also add an `Async` suffix.

```
public async Task<int> DoWorkAsync()
{
  return await DoLongRunningWorkAsync();
}
```

> 4. Change calling methods to use `await`, and repeat step (3).

In this case, since `Main` cannot be `async`, you'll need to block with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, just like you currently have.

Final result:

```
public async Task<int> DoWorkAsync()
{
  return await DoLongRunningWorkAsync();
}

public async Task<int> DoLongRunningWorkAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  return 1;
}
```

---

> I was expecting Main method's ManagedThreadId will be different than DoWorkAsync and DoLongRunningWorkAsync method's ManagedThreadId. But they are same, why?

"Asynchronous" does ***NOT*** mean "runs on a different thread." See my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more details about how `async`/`await` works.

Comment: @LP13: Your update completely changes your question and the appropriate answers. Please post a new question.